# Unable to access SQL Server 2008 - Cannot Generate SSPI Context

Tags: sql-server-2008, kerberos

I've had this problem for a few weeks but haven't had time to focus on it until now. My company has a relatively fresh installation of Windows Server 2011, which is also running Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Everything was running along fine, until one day we had an unexpected power outage and the server died.

I restarted and thought everything was fine, but when I tried to access the SQL server, I received the message `Cannot generate SSPI context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)`. I did a soft shutdown of both the server and the client computer, and it temporarily worked, but it has since reverted to giving the `Cannot generate SSPI context` error and I have no idea why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already tried [Josh's - How to fix SQL Server Error](http://joshrobi.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-fix-sql-server-error-cannot.html) or [SQL Server Connectivity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/19/482782.aspx) or [error on remote connection](http://kamivaniea.com/?p=295)?

Comment: @Joshua Drake Thanks for the tip, but I already migrated to MySQL instead. Although I will keep this in mind for future projects